# Spatial separation in analogy to time separation in Lorentzian geometry?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, causality

O'Neill (Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity, 1983, p. 409) defines time separation between two events as follows:

> "If $p, q \in M$, the time separation $\tau(p, q)$ from $p$ to $q$ is $\sup\{L(\alpha): \alpha$ is a future-pointing causal curve segment from $p$ to $q \}$."

[image]

Later on, it is found that

> **in globally hyperbolic spacetimes** any pair of points that can be joined by a causal curve can be joined by a (longest) causal geodesic (with counterexamples for spacetimes that are not globally hyperbolic).

For **what kind of spacetimes** does it make sense to define an analogous notion of spatial separation $\sigma(p, q)$ as $\sup\{L(\alpha): \alpha$ is a spacelike curve segment from $p$ to $q \}$? Is global-hyperbolicity relevant again?

Comment: I think there is some issue with MathJax. I think it would be helpful if you could also attach a picture of the page in O'Neil for reference.

Comment: Thanks, @VaibhavK

Comment: In the general case, when you want to compute the separation of two events $p, q\in M$, you simply consider the line-element -- here the reference is only to whether or not an event lies in the future causal domain $J^{+}(p)$, If you generalize this to $J^{\pm }(p)$, you would get the set of all future (and past) causal curves. For spacelike separation, this becomes different -- you simply consider the set of all spacelike curves. So, if a point $p$ does not lie in $J^{\pm }(q)$, then any curve $\gamma $ joining $p$ and $q$ must be spacelike. Global hyperbolicity is a slightly related aspect.

Comment: I would recommend (as I have been to everyone) referring to Hawking and Ellis. It captures all of these aspects quite concisely and technically. Global hyperbolicity is related, but the intuition as to why it _should_ be related is perhaps a little more technical. If this is what you are looking for, I can turn this into an answer.

Comment: Comment on terminology and notation: Symbol $\tau$ does typically denote duration (a.k.a. "proper time", a.k.a. "length of a segment of a timelike arc"); e.g. $\tau_{\gamma}[ \, p, q \, ]$ denoting specifically the duration of any participant having passed from event $p$ to event $q$ along spacetime path $\gamma$. Quantity $$\underset{\gamma \, \in \, \Gamma_p^q}{\text{Sup}}[ \, \{ \tau_{\gamma}[ \, p, q \, ] \} \, ] $$ is also known as [(asymm.) Lorentzian distance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Lorentzian+distance%22); denoted as $\ell[ \, p, q \, ]$, or as $d[ \, p, q \, ]$.

Comment: Also: Symbol $\sigma$ denotes (values of) [Synge's world function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synge%27s_world_function).